# What is low bit ambient mode in watch?

Tags: wear-os

I am creating watch-face, every where term low bit ambient mode included in document, I am not 100% sure what it is and how to visualize it.

What is anti aliasing with that ? how to visualize this property and use in watch face ?

Answer (score 5):

The best explanation I've seen is from the *Reduced color space* section of [this page](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html):

> Some displays use a reduced color space in ambient mode to save power.
>
> One reduced color space power saving method is to use a "low-bit"
>   mode. In low-bit mode, the available colors are limited to black,
>   white, blue, red, magenta, green, cyan, and yellow... You should also
>   disable antialiasing in your paint styles for this mode. Make sure to
>   test your design on devices with low-bit ambient mode.

To assist with the last point (testing), there's a setting in **Developer options**, under **Wear developer options**, called **Force low-bit ambient**. Turn that on, and your watch (or emulator) will use low-bit ambient mode, simulating what the display will look like on a watch that always uses this mode (like a Sony SW3 or Asus ZenWatch).